# Asymptote remaking every file

Tags: pdftex, asymptote

My `main.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
    \asyinclude{first.asy}
    \asyinclude{second.asy}
\end{document}
```

To make a pdf, I have to run:

```
pdflatex main.tex
asy main-1.asy
asy main-2.asy
pdflatex main.tex
```

If I swap positions of `\asyinclude{first.asy}` and `\asyinclude{second.asy}`, I have to completely rerun the four commands, similarly if I add another `\asyinclude` at the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}
    \asyinclude{third.asy}
    \asyinclude{first.asy}
    \asyinclude{second.asy}
\end{document}
```

Here I have to remake all the pdf files because all of the `main-*.asy` will change (shift by one) after running `pdflatex main.tex`. This can sometimes take more that 10 minutes depending on how many figures I have after the inserted one.

Is there an elegant way of speeding the process up?

Comment: [asypictureB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlkJih6-DQAhVQ3GMKHbVLCyAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Fpkg%2Fasypictureb%3Flang%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHadUPBi7Fnxc3tyu0siLRO5on-Jg&sig2=T9X-pSgBTw4l47fyS2ubpQ&bvm=bv.140496471,d.cGc)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Thanks, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, in case you are not aware, you may compile your `.asy` files directly at the command line using a command such as `asy first -f pdf`.  Then include the resulting `first.pdf` in your LaTeX document as a graphic.